# When I use sDom to remove element from the toolbar of datatable I lose the background color too

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm trying to customize the toolbar of my `Datatable`. I'm using version `1.10` and I include `jquery-ui` so my reasearch shows a lot of suggestions of how to add/remove element but I can't find concrete example, and my code is not giving the dsired result.

So basically for starters I want to remove the default `search box` (and later add custom filters) so I add this script:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
            "sDom": '<"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
```

which actually removes the `search box` that i don't need but also I loose my out og the box styling (or at least I think that is what happens) because before including `"sDom":...` I got a nice coloerd background with border, and after I include it I loose the styling and get only blank space.

I would appreciate an example on how to remove the `search box` I think here I use the older way of changing the look, an example based on `jQuery-ui` is also acceptable.

Comment: can you please share a jsfiddle of it.

Comment: Not really sure how to include the `Datatables` resources in JSFiddle example. I'm using the very basic setup trying to stick to this example - https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/jqueryui-simple.html, but making some customizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove default search box you can use `"bFilter": false`, see below code:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
            "bFilter": false,...
             });
```

Comment: I wanted to use `sDom` specifically because from what I've read `"bFilter": false,` removes some other functionalities not only the search box. And  I don't know if I never gonna use them so I prefer to stick to the suggested approach which is `sDom`. However if no better answer is given I'll accept yours.